# sling test case SERVER side

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, integration-testing, sling

I was writing sling unit test case for server side , where my test bundle is run by getting hit into the junit servlet , from the client side using the following piece of code. My test needs a running FTP server for the purpose , which i want to get embed into this function , by using @before and cleaning the dump by @after or any other best possible ways , how to do this with the runnable test class which invokes a junit servlet.

```
@RunWith(SlingRemoteTestRunner.class)
    public class FTPImporterTest extends SlingTestBase implements SlingRemoteTestParameters, SlingTestsCountChecker {
        /**
         *
         */
        public static final String TEST_SELECTOR = "com.my.proj.FTPImporterTesting.FTPImporterServerTest";
        public static final int TESTS_AT_THIS_PATH = 3;
        /**
         *
         */

        public int getExpectedNumberOfTests() { 
            return TESTS_AT_THIS_PATH;
        }

        public String getJunitServletUrl() {
            return getServerBaseUrl() + "/system/sling/junit";
        }

        public String getTestClassesSelector() {
            return TEST_SELECTOR;
        }

        public String getTestMethodSelector() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkNumberOfTests(int i) {
            Assert.assertEquals(TESTS_AT_THIS_PATH, i);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to use [Mockito framework](http://mockito.org) .

Here's an example of using [Mocktio in AEM](http://www.practicalaem.com/2016/01/19/testing-using-mockito/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the newer approach with the [Sling Teleporter Junit Rule](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/org-apache-sling-junit-bundles.html#the-teleporterrule). It allows for writing tests that run on the client-side but the inner JUnit Statement is replaced on the client-side and teleported in sling, where it runs using the junit core framework.

Here is the example in the docs:

```java
public class BasicTeleporterTest {

@Rule
public final TeleporterRule teleporter = TeleporterRule.forClass(getClass(), "Launchpad");

@Test
public void testConfigAdmin() throws IOException {
    final String pid = "TEST_" + getClass().getName() + UUID.randomUUID();

    final ConfigurationAdmin ca = teleporter.getService(ConfigurationAdmin.class);
    assertNotNull("Teleporter should provide a ConfigurationAdmin", ca);

    final Configuration cfg = ca.getConfiguration(pid);
    assertNotNull("Expecting to get a Configuration", cfg);
    assertEquals("Expecting the correct pid", pid, cfg.getPid());
}
```

}